# get the text of the link tapped in uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am using the code below to detect a link tap on my uiwebview. Is there a way to get the text of the link that has been tapped by the user?

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"link tapped");
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {


        //if (overrideLinksSwitch.on == TRUE) {
             NSLog(@"navigation link tapped");
          //  [self myMethodAction];

          //  [myWebView stopLoading];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linktapped]];
            return NO;
        }



    return YES;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the URL that was selected by the user?

Comment: Yes bschultz that is what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURLRequest` has a `URL` property. [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Just get the URL from the `request` object in your method.