# How to get the description for a link tapped in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How can I get the description of a link that a user has tapped in the `UIWebView` before loading the request? 
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636342/get-the-text-of-the-link-tapped-in-uiwebview) seemed to ask the same thing, but what he actually wanted was the URL, which is not my case. I just want to know what is the text description of the link that has been tapped by the user.

Comment: When you say "text description" do you mean the value displayed in the `<a>` tag or some sort of summary of the contents?

Comment: the text value inside the <a> tag. i.e: <a href="www.something.com">*this is what i want*</a>

Comment: Do you have control over the way the html data comes to you i.e. can you edit the html to include additional detail?

Comment: I'd rather assume I don't. It is kind of predictable, but it might change.

Comment: Well, one obvious way is to use javascript to enumerate all `<a>` elements and match the one that has this URL. Obviously, if multiple hyperlinks exist with the same URL, there would be no way to distinguish between them, but perhaps you can live with it?